# How to make a parent div auto size to the width of its children divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the parent div only as wide as the child div's. Auto width is making the parent div fit the entire screen. The children divs will be different widths depending on their content so I need the parent div to adjust accordingly.

```
<div style='width:auto;'>
  <div style="width: 135px; float: left;">
    <h4 style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 15px;">Column1</h4>
    <dl style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 15px; margin-top: -8px; overflow-x: hidden;">
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">1</dd>
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">2</dd>
    </dl>

    <h4 style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 15px;">Column1</h4>
    <dl style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 15px; margin-top: -8px; overflow-x: hidden;">
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">1</dd>
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">2</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 135px; float: right;">
    <h4 style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 10px;">Column2</h4>
    <dl style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 15px; margin-top: -8px; overflow-x: hidden;">
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">1</dd>
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">2</dd>
      <dd style="white-space: nowrap;">3</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Your interior `<div>` elements should likely both be `float:left`.  Divs size to 100% the size of their container width automatically.  Try using `display:inline-block` instead of `width:auto` on the container div.  Or possibly `float:left` the container and also apply `overflow:auto`.  Depends on what you're after exactly.

Comment: overflow auto did it for me

Comment: "display:inline-block" is a nice way, but if you want to use percentage value for the width of the child element, it will not work as you expect.
Any idea to make it work with the percentage values too?

Comment: @MohsenHaeri you can't. Percentage width for child is calculated from width of the parent. Think about it, if I have two children with `width: 50%` how wide is the parent?

Comment: @Madbreaks I know that. That's why I'm looking for a hack to do that. Js ways are available, but I couldn't figure out a pure css way. Anyway, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 57):

this is the easiest way to make your parent div inherit it's child width.

```css
.container-fluid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*the needed css class to make your parent div responsive to it's children's max-width
  */
  width: max-content
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wrapper">xxx</div>
</div>
```

i hope someone finds this usefull

Answer (score 38):

The parent div (I assume the outermost div) is `display: block` and will fill up all available width of its container (in this case, the body) that it can.  Using a different display type -- `inline-block` is probably what you are going for:

http://jsfiddle.net/a78xy/

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this and was setting the width of my parent component. As an accident, I found out the CSS `width: fit-content`;

Here is an example:

```css
.outerContainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
}

.innerContainer {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example the `innerContainer` div (the one with a red background) fits to the content of the `item` container. The `outerContainer` div is there to show the contrast.

Comment: Be careful to check how supported this is and if you shall you is or not for your project https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content